# Angular 7 error notification doesn't show up

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I inherited a really big Angular application which I had to upgrade from 5.2 to 7.2. I managed to do that, but there is one error I can't resolve.

// EDIT

**I found a solution, but I don't know if it's valid or not**..

```
processReportResponse(response: HttpResponse<any>) {
    if (response.status === 204) {
      throw new HttpErrorResponse({ error: 'NoDataError' });
    } else {
      return new Blob([response.body], { type: 'application/pdf' });
    }
  }
```

// END EDIT

We are generating reports based on certain inputs. When you click to generate, the `createdSalesByDateReport` function is getting called which looks like this:

```
createSalesByDateReport() {
    const fromTemp = new Date(this.from);
    let toTemp = new Date(this.to);

    if (this.selectMonth) {
      // select the whole month of the from date
      fromTemp.setDate(1);
      toTemp = new Date(fromTemp.getFullYear(), fromTemp.getMonth() + 1, 0);
      toTemp.setHours(23, 59, 59, 999);
      // setting day to 0 means one day less than first day of the month
    }

    this.startLoading();
    if (!this.userSelectionDisabled && this.selectedUserIds && this.selectedUserIds.length > 0) {
      this.createUserSalesReport(fromTemp, toTemp, this.selectedUserIds);
    } else {
      this.createOrganizationSalesReport(fromTemp, toTemp, this.selectedUserGroupIds);
    }
  }
```

Since we are creating user sales reports, it's always the `createUserSalesReport()` that is getting called:

```
createUserSalesReport(from: Date, to: Date, userIds: string[]) {
    this.reportService.getOrganizationUsersSalesReport(from, to, userIds)
      .subscribe(
        reportResponse => this.userGroupsSalesResponse(reportResponse, from, to),
        res => this.processServerException(res)
      );
  }
```

This will call the reporting service's `getOrganizationUsersSalesReport()` function:

```
getOrganizationUsersSalesReport(from: Date, to: Date, userIds: string[]): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(this.url + 'userSales?from=' + from.getTime() +
      '&to=' + to.getTime() + '&timezone=' + Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone + '&userIds='
      + userIds.map(function (userId) { return userId; }),
      { observe: 'response', responseType: 'blob' })
      .pipe(map(res => {
        this.processReportResponse(res);
      }));
  }
```

This goes to the service's `processReportResponse()` function:

```
processReportResponse(response: any) {
    if (response.status === 204) {
      throw throwError('NoDataError');
    } else {
      return new Blob([response.body], { type: 'application/pdf' });
    }
  }
```

Since we subscribe to the response in the component's `createUserSalesReport()` function (seen above), it's either and error or a Blob.

In my case a notification should pop up with the given error, because the service's `processReportResponse()` got an `HttpResponse` with the status of 204 and this passes an error to the component's `createUserSalesReport()` function, so the `processServerException()` function gets called:

```
processServerException(res: any) {
    console.log(res);
    this.stopLoading();
    if (res.error && res.error === 'NoDataError') {
      this.alertService.info(this.translateService.instant('reporting.nodata'));
    }
  }
```

But unfortunately the response is in a format what I can not check or read, so the condition doesn't pass the content of the response to the `alertService`

This is the response's format:

[image]

I would like to get the error response in such format when I can check the content of it and the condition in the `processServerException()` can pass it to the `alertService`.

Comment: `switchMap`! :)

Comment: @AJT_82 I don't want to be stupid, I am new to Angular. Could you please explain it a bit? :)

Comment: Well, I wasn't that explanatory, as I was at work :D But I wrote up an answer for you now. Hope it helps :)

Comment: I updated the whole question, there was a misunderstanding in the initial explanation of the problem. Sorry for the inconvenience..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this :

```
import { Observable, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError, map } from 'rxjs/operators';
processReportResponse(response: HttpResponse<any>) {
if (response.status === 204) {
  throw throwError({error: 'NoDataError'});
} else {
  return new Blob([response.body], { type: 'application/pdf' });
}}
```

Comment: Do you mean the processReportResponse() in the second block?

Comment: i'm sorry i've missed th real issue, i've updated my answer

Comment: This answer led me to the solution, I edited the question accordingly and It presents the proper solution too.

Answer (score 0):

You need to flatten the result, to return an observable from the second request. Now you are returning an observable of an observable. To flatten the result we can use [`switchMap`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/switchmap.html):

```
import { switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators'

// ...

return this.http.get(...)
  .pipe(
    switchMap(res => { // change map to switchmap!
      return this.processReportResponse(res);
    })
   );
```

Comment: I updated the whole question, there was a misunderstanding in the initial explanation of the problem. Sorry for the inconvenience..